# Is there any public transport from Punta Arenas, Chile to El Calafate, Argentina?

Tags: public-transport, chile, argentina, patagonia

I'd like to visit Perito Moreno Glacier while I'll be in Patagonia. I'm not sure where I will depart from, but my options are **Punta Arenas**, **Puerto Natales** or [EcoCamp Patagonia](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g670171-d598885-Reviews-Ecocamp_Patagonia-Torres_del_Paine_Patagonia.html). 
Do you know whether there is any public transport from these locations to **El Calafate**? If so, where can I check its schedule?

How long it takes to get to the El Calafate (including time on a border)?

Is it safe to drive there by yourself?

I've heard that sometimes the road is closed due to weather conditions, so what time of the year would you recommend to visit the Glaciers and Torres Del Paine?

Comment: Good question though I would narrow down the scope from 5 to 1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are.  There are several bus lines that I could find online though I could only find 1 that provides cross border routes:

- [Buses Pacheco](http://www.busespacheco.com)

If you look at their schedule you will find that they have a bus from [Puerto Natales to El Calafate](http://www.busespacheco.com/rutas.htm) and a connecting bus from Punta Arenas to Puerto Natales though I can't find the trip duration so it is possible that you may have to spend the night at Puerto Natales.